# Random-points-from-Classification tool (EnMAP-Box plugin) - Adding mask option by python? (QGIS 3.16, Win10)

Tags: point, classification, masking, random, enmap-box

I created random-point-vector-files from a classified rasters with a given number of points per class by the *Random points from Classification* tool (EnMAP-Box plugin). But, now I'd like to exclude certain areas from being placed points there. Unfortunately the tool is quite basic and has no mask option. (You can only specify your raster, number of random points per class, and type of vector output.)

Is it possible to run the tool from the Python console and to implement a mask option by Python there?

I am not familiar to python, just some patchy and very basic knowledge.

Comment: Mask your raster.

Comment: If you mean to prepare my raster according to my mask in advance. Yes, this would be principally an option, but for several reasons not that kind of solution I am looking for.
Best for me would be a Random-Points_from-Classification-tool where Í can specify a mask, - as this works with a lot of other tools. But as I could only find the depicted tool, I would like - or hope at least -  to find a way to implement a mask by python or another method.